# Programatically download/export search usage reports

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, reports, sharepoint-search

Is there a way to use powershell or the object model to schedule downloads of the various usage reports available in central admin, search service administration for sharepoint 2013 (or sharepoint online?). The reports I'm interested in are

- Number of Queries
- Top Queries by Month/Day
- Abandoned Queries by Month/Day
- No Result Queries by Month/Day

We have a group of business users working continuously on improving search by analysing these reports and they don't have access to central admin, and they never will. Currently operations staff extract and email the reports, but we would like to automate this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do they have access to the Search Center Site Collection? The reports are available there as well. Site Settings | Popularity and Search Reports.

Comment: In both report locations there doesn't look there is a way to automate the downloads ( emailing)  each of the reports listed: Flows, RSS notifications etc.

Comment: Nope, there isn't. You'd have to create your own process to download and save them.

Comment: Ah I promised my delivery manager I would email you Matt but you got in there first! Thanks